# Bind service to activity in Android

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to write a simple media player that plays streaming audio using RTSP. I have a GUI-activity and a service that performs the playback. My question is how to best communicate between the activity and the service (e.g. updating the GUI based on the player state).

I know that I can bind the service to the activity using onBind(), but if I understand correctly this will stop the service if the activity is killed. I want to continue the playback even if the user exits the activity. Is there any standard or preferred way of dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

"If you start an android Service with `startService(..)` that Service will remain running until you explicitly invoke `stopService(..)`.
There are two reasons that a service can be run by the system. If someone calls `Context.startService()` then the system will retrieve the service (creating it and calling its `onCreate()` method if needed) and then call its `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` method with the arguments supplied by the client. The service will at this point continue running until `Context.stopService()` or `stopSelf()` is called. Note that multiple calls to `Context.startService()` do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to `onStartCommand()`), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once `Context.stopService()` or `stopSelf()` is called; however, services can use their `stopSelf(int)` method to ensure the service is not stopped until started intents have been processed.

Clients can also use `Context.bindService()` to obtain a persistent connection to a service. This likewise creates the service if it is not already running (calling `onCreate()` while doing so), but does not call `onStartCommand()`. The client will receive the `IBinder` object that the service returns from its `onBind(Intent)` method, allowing the client to then make calls back to the service. The service will remain running as long as the connection is established (whether or not the client retains a reference on the Service's `IBinder`). Usually the `IBinder` returned is for a complex interface that has been written in AIDL.

A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with the `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag. Once neither of these situations hold, the Service's `onDestroy()` method is called and the service is effectively terminated. All cleanup (stopping threads, unregistering receivers) should be complete upon returning from `onDestroy()`."

Comment: a little confusion: Is it true that if the activity is destroyed the service will also be destroyed? Or is that service not destroyed only if I implement my own AIDL? I am asking because when I use startService (esp on IntentService) the service stops when its work is done as opposed to when the activity dies. So is it true that if the activity dies, then the service that is bound (exclusively) also dies?

Comment: if you are using simple server by calling startService then service will not stop until you call stopSelf() or stopService(). And the next if you use bindService then yes service will die if all connected/bind component destroy.

Comment: @UnKnown If the service is started using startService() then no matter if you bind or unbind it, it will keep on running and can only be destroyed by either calling stopService() or stopSelf(). So, even if the activity that was bounded to the service is destroyed the service won't get destroyed.

Answer (score 28):

First of all, 2 thing that we need to understand

### Client

- it make request to specific server

  ```
  bindService(new 
      Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
          mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`
  ```

here `mServiceConn` is instance of `ServiceConnection` class(inbuilt) it is actually interface that we need to implement with two (1st for network connected and 2nd network not connected) method to monitor network connection state.

### Server

- It handle the request of client and make replica of it's own which is private to client only who send request and this replica of server runs on different thread.

### Now at client side, how to access all the method of server?

- server send response with IBind Object.so IBind object is our handler which access all the method of service by using (.) operator.

  ```
  MyService myService;
  public ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
          Log.d("ServiceConnection","connected");
          myService = binder;
      }
      //binder comes from server to communicate with method's of 

      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
          Log.d("ServiceConnection","disconnected");
          myService = null;
      }
  }
  ```

### now how to call method which lies in service

```
myservice.serviceMethod();
```

here `myService` is object and `serviceMethode` is method in service.
And by this way communication is established between client and server.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to call

```
startService(oIntent);
bindService(oIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

consequently and I could create a sticky service and bind to it. Detailed tutorial for [Bound Service Example](http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/).

Answer (score 5):

There is a method called [unbindService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService(android.content.ServiceConnection)) that will take a ServiceConnection which you will have created upon calling bindService. This will allow you to disconnect from the service while still leaving it running.

This may pose a problem when you connect to it again, since you probably don't know whether it's running or not when you start the activity again, so you'll have to consider that in your activity code.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

This is a biased answer, but I wrote a library that may simplify the usage of Android Services, if they run locally in the same process as the app: https://github.com/germnix/acacia

Basically you define an interface annotated with @Service and its implementing class, and the library creates and binds the service, handles the connection and the background worker thread:

```
@Service(ServiceImpl.class)
public interface MyService {
    void doProcessing(Foo aComplexParam);
}

public class ServiceImpl implements MyService {
    // your implementation
}

MyService service = Acacia.createService(context, MyService.class);
service.doProcessing(foo);

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
    <service android:name="com.gmr.acacia.AcaciaService"/>
    ...
</application>
```

You can get an instance of the associated android.app.Service to hide/show persistent notifications, use your own android.app.Service and manually handle threading if you wish.

Answer (score -5):

If the user backs out, the `onDestroy()` method will be called. This method is to stop any service that is used in the application. So if you want to continue the service even if the user backs out of the application, just erase `onDestroy()`. Hope this help.

Comment: You'd have to override the function and delete the default call to the superclass's onDestroy() if your IDE automatically creates one. but why would you ever want to do this?