# Stay locked after call in custom lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to create custom lock screen in android with pattern code. I know how to make a custom lock screen [example](https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp) and a pattern lock [example](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/PatternLock), but I want to add to my custom lock screen an option to call a specific contact from the lock screen, even if it locked.

What is the best way to allow the user call someone, but after the call was ended the user should return to the lock screen (similar to emergency call). Notice that the user shouldn't use the key pad, the number is defined by configuring the app.

You can imagine it like the camera, which you can access to even when the phone is locked, but you still need the code for accessing the whole phone.

Comment: well you have to bind to call service , which is provided by Android with AIDL and when you start the call you will place a flag like LOCKED . when the call is ended , you ll have to check the flag and if its LOCKED then return to the lock screen , otherwise default

Comment: Thanks, what is the Intent name of the call service?

Comment: you could find it easily in Google's Android documentation because i havent tested myself for the latest version , or check this solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844930/how-to-call-methods-of-a-service-from-activity