# Android service method call

Tags: android

I want to call the method of a service 1 in service 2 of same app.
For example there is Method1 in service 1.

```
public void Method1(){
....}
```

and in service 2 my code will be as...

```
Service1 serviceOne_object=new Service1();
service1_object.Method1();
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call methods of a Service from activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844930/how-to-call-methods-of-a-service-from-activity)

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. You can pass data between services using standard android intent mechanism.

Service1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service2.class);
intent.putExtra("call_some_method", true);
startService(intent);
```

Service2:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent != null && intent.getBooleanExtra("call_some_method", false)) {
        Method1();
    }
}
```