# How to stop Alarm tone pragmatically in android studio

Tags: java, android

My alarm code is working fine as default ringtone is playing well on time. But not able to stop the alarm tone. In receiver class I inserted the following code.

```
try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also inserted the code for cancel the alarm in main class, which is also working well with the code

```
alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

But once the default ringtone start playing and user want to stop this by stop button then it is not working.
In main class with stopbutton.setOnClickListener I inserted the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Reciver.class);
stopService(intent);
```

I think it can be stop by r.stop();
but how should I use it in stop button.

Comment: No getting exactly, If I am not wrong you put the stop button on your own UI but it's not working , Am i right ?

Comment: I have three button in main layout connected with main class. start button call the alarm manager and wake up receiver class (r.play is here in this class) and working well. Cancel button cancel the alarm. now the third button is the stop button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Global instance of `Ringtone` and on button click use `r.stop()` use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23216853/5255006) to perform the operation in service. Let me know if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: I did the coding as per your suggestion and it worked. Thanks a lot brother.

Comment: If it is helpful then please upvote it, it will be helpful to others also

Comment: How to do it? Should I choose the upper arrow?

Comment: ok, I am doing this and it is saying "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

A broadcast intent registered while you schedule the alarm but to ensure a cancel you have to registered another intent that would boradcast cancel event to system.

Look at piece of code working fine during a cancel event.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 123, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```