# Android: calling method of background service from activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an App for mobile phone that talk with another App on my SmartWatch.
The phone App **must** run in background, of course, in order to send some data to the watch and act in some cases as Proxy.
I wrote a service, that will be started on boot. This service was successfully started on boot and it can initialize the GoogleAPI and so on.
Now, if I start my Main Activity, in order to change some settings, I need the service to send data to the smart watch.
To do that I call some public method of my service and I need to be sure, that the service was started...
The code in my Activity:

```
Log.v(PROGRAM, "Starting background service");
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PilotWatchService.class);
getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
service = new PilotWatchService();

Log.d(PROGRAM, String.format("System is %s", service.isOnline() ? "online" : "offline"));
```

as soon I call service.isOnline() the app crashes with the error:

```
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.lucabert.pilotwatch/de.lucabert.pilotwatch.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:659)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at de.lucabert.pilotwatch.PilotWatchService.isOnline(PilotWatchService.java:282)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at de.lucabert.pilotwatch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:116)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
05-19 21:49:55.074  7292  7292 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
05-19 21:49:55.075  1686  2020 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity de.lucabert.pilotwatch/.MainActivity
```

I really can't understand how I can use the function of my service in my Activity. Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot
Luca

Comment: Maybe this thread could help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844930/how-to-call-methods-of-a-service-from-activity

Comment: Hi ali! Thank you very much! It works! But I have a little problem... as soon as I close the Activity, the Service will be closed, too... I want my Service to continue running in order to serve data to my watch... How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I think you want the functionalities of foreground services.
I hope this page from documentation can help you:
https://developer.android.com/guide/background