# Bind service to any incoming SMS/Emails/Calls?

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am new to Android services so please excuse the "noobish" question. How could I bind a `Service` to any incoming SMS, calls, or email? Should I use the `onBind` method? Or should I use a `BroadcastReciever`?

Comment: this post will be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916253/bind-service-to-activity-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I bind a Service to any incoming SMS, calls, or email?

You don't.

Handling incoming SMSes technically is not supported by the Android SDK. There is a broadcast `Intent` that is sent out when an SMS comes in whose action, unfortunately, is undocumented. If you were to use this, you would need a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`.

There is an `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` `Intent` that is broadcast whenever the phone is in use, but this includes incoming and outgoing calls. Once again you would need a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`.

Either of those `BroadcastReceiver` objects could (and perhaps should) pass control to an `IntentService` via `startService()`, so the service can do the real work.

There is no concept of "email" in the Android OS. That is an application concept. At this point, there are probably more email applications for Android than you have bones in your body. Few, if any, have a documented and supported API, such as broadcast `Intents`, AFAIK.

Comment: Would you happen to know the intent filter's action that receives gmail or mail application?

Comment: @Mohit Deshpande: There are no "intent filter's action that receives gmail or mail application".

Comment: Doesn't the gmail/mail application have to publish something to notify the Android OS of the email?

Comment: @Mohit Deshpande: There is no concept of "email" in the Android OS. That is an application concept. Outlook doesn't tell Windows "of the email". Thunderbird doesn't tell Windows or Linux "of the email".