# Send data from activity to running service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a short question. How can I send data from an activity to an already running service?

The approach is as following, I have a service running in the background, which is starting a new activity that is just showing an input window. And now I want to send the typed data back to the service. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance for helping!
Best regards
Tobi

Comment: Schildmeijer gave a clear anwser on a similair problem in another post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916253/bind-service-to-activity-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of [onBind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind%28android.content.Intent%29) method of [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class?

Comment: Oh, ok, perhaps I just thought to complicated... With the OnBind method I can give back a string within the intent, am I right?

Comment: were u rght at the end? how to read it in service? it's not same as activity2activity communication (getExtras..) 10q

Comment: So do we need to bind to share data with service then unbind and then again bind when we need to share data? Is this the correct way of communicating with a running Service from an Activity?