# How to send message from activity to intentService?

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I have an intentService in my app that I use to play music files in the background.
In this service, I have several methods (play, pause, stop, etc.) that I need to call from my main fragment in response to UI input.
However I cant seem to find any way of sending messages to an intentservice, I can only find ways to sending messages from an intentService to an activity.

If someone knows a way I can achieve this, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: [Still.....!!!!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4300291/2389078)

Comment: [Did you read doc?](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html)

Comment: The doc for IntentService says: "Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls". Did you try calling startService from your main fragment?

Comment: Hi, Sorry i think i didnt explain very well. I need to be able to send messages to my running intentservice. For example, when i have started the service and it is playing a music file, i want to be able to then call a method in the service to pause the music playback in response to a button press in my main fragment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6225157/1777090

Comment: I am doing same with the link that I posted above. I used service to play music. your comment on this thread just says you haven't done enough research. That's not much of a work. Please try to read the docs and see the example that I posted above.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but I am using an IntentService, not the standard Service class. Thanks anyway though, Corey

Comment: DroidDev, Yes i read the link you gave, but the problem is i am using an IntentService, not a standard Service. IntentService does not use methods such as OnBind, etc.

Comment: Is there any compulsion of using Intent service, if you can't do what you want with it. You can also try just using service. Sorry, if I was arrogant earlier.

Comment: @DroidDev, The reason i have been using IntentService is it makes handling the seperate threads, updating the ui, etc much easier (saves me having to write all the code myself). But i will have a look into using just a standard service, and whether i can do what i require with it. Thanks again for all your help, Corey B :)