# bind/unbind service example (android)

Tags: android, binding, service

can you give me a simple example of an application with background service which uses bind/unbind methods to start and stop it? I was googling for it for a half-hour, but those examples use startService/stopService methods or are very difficult for me. thank you.

Comment: You can read about this in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916253/bind-service-to-activity-in-android

Comment: ye,i've already read it for 3 times, but my bad - i can't get it. i need an example with main activity and service activity

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can try using this code:

```
protected ServiceConnection mServerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
    }
}

public void start() {
    // mContext is defined upper in code, I think it is not necessary to explain what is it 
    mContext.bindService(intent, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mContext.startService(intent);
}

public void stop() {
    mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, ServiceRemote.class));
    mContext.unbindService(mServerConn);
}
```

Comment: tell me please, what is varialbe i?

Comment: i = new Intent, like this: new Intent(this, YourService.class)

Comment: Thanks for this Dawid, can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341782/good-practise-for-services-on-android , I have an issue related to Services, and advanced service life management, but no answers yet :'(

Comment: I am voting u bro :) this is least I can do :(

Comment: i wonder why @DawidSajdak put the new Intent when he want to stop the Intent? Wouldn't be the same if he put the previous intent object over that onStop() method?

Comment: I suspect the above answer was hastily written. For a complete example of binding a `Service` with full explanation, see [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Local_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example).

Comment: You should keep in mind that onStop() may not be called if the activity is killed due to a low memory.

Answer (score 47):

Add these methods to your Activity:

```
private MyService myServiceBinder;
public ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        myServiceBinder = ((MyService.MyBinder) binder).getService();
        Log.d("ServiceConnection","connected");
        showServiceData();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.d("ServiceConnection","disconnected");
        myService = null;
    }
};

public Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        Bundle data = message.getData();
    }
};

public void doBindService() {
    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(this, BTService.class);
    // Create a new Messenger for the communication back
    // From the Service to the Activity
    Messenger messenger = new Messenger(myHandler);
    intent.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);

    bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

And you can bind to service by ovverriding *onResume()*, and *onPause()* at your Activity class.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    Log.d("activity", "onResume");
    if (myService == null) {
        doBindService();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    //FIXME put back

    Log.d("activity", "onPause");
    if (myService != null) {
        unbindService(myConnection);
        myService = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Note, that when binding to a service only the `onCreate()` method is called in the service class.
In your Service class you need to define the myBinder method:

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
private Messenger outMessenger;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Bundle extras = arg0.getExtras();
    Log.d("service","onBind");
    // Get messager from the Activity
    if (extras != null) {
        Log.d("service","onBind with extra");
        outMessenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");
    }
    return mBinder;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

After you defined these methods you can reach the methods of your service at your Activity:

```
private void showServiceData() {  
    myServiceBinder.myMethod();
}
```

and finally you can start your service when some event occurs like  _BOOT_COMPLETED_

```
public class MyReciever  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Intent service = new Intent(context, myService.class);
            context.startService(service);
        }
    }
}
```

note that when starting a service the `onCreate()` and `onStartCommand()` is called in service class
and you can stop your service when another event occurs by *stopService()*
note that your event listener should be registerd in your Android manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReciever" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: @Hib Why un/binding on Pauser/Resume ? Google docs [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) highly discourage this. They advise on Start/Stop.

Comment: @hannunehg when I wrote this answer start stop not existed - please edit my answer or later I will do it

Comment: very nice answer - still useful to this day

Comment: Do I need to check if the activity still available before sending a message to its handler?

Answer (score 17):

First of all, two things that we need to understand,

### Client

- It makes request to a specific server

`bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
            mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

here `mServiceConn` is instance of `ServiceConnection` class(inbuilt) it is actually interface 
that we need to implement with two (1st for network connected and 2nd network not connected) method to monitor network connection state.

### Server

- It handles the request of the client and makes replica of its own which is private to client only who send request and this raplica of server runs on different thread.

### Now at client side, how to access all the methods of server?

- Server sends response with `IBinder` Object. So, `IBinder` object is our handler which accesses all the methods of `Service` by using (.) operator.

.

```
MyService myService;
public ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        Log.d("ServiceConnection","connected");
        myService = binder;
    }
    //binder comes from server to communicate with method's of 

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.d("ServiceConnection","disconnected");
        myService = null;
    }
}
```

### Now how to call method which lies in service

```
myservice.serviceMethod();
```

Here `myService` is object and serviceMethod is method in service.
and by this way communication is established between client and server.