# how can i add image in listview by service handler?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-image

I am new on android. I create a list view , I used service handler to fetch data from server. I want to add image in my `ListView` and get images from server. The snippet of my code is following:

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://api-11hr.anovatesoft.com/v1/list";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER = "contactnumber";
    private static final String TAG_POSTAL_CODE = "postalcode";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
    SessionManager session;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String apikey;
    GPSTracker gps;


    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        Gps_func();


        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();


        // apikey
        // Calling Application class (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
        final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();

        //Set name and email in global/application context
        apikey = globalVariable.getApikey();


        latitude = globalVariable.getLatitude();
        longitude = globalVariable.getLongitude();


        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();


                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Adds.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);

                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private void Gps_func() {

        gps = new GPSTracker(Home.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // \n is for new line
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("tag", "Longitude:\n" + longitude + "\n Latitude: \n" + latitude);

        } else {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();

            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("tag", "Longitude:\n" + longitude + "\n Latitude: \n" + latitude);

            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Gps_func();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler1 sh = new ServiceHandler1(apikey, latitude, longitude);


            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler1.POST);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER);
                        String postalcode = c.getString(TAG_POSTAL_CODE);


                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Home.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item1, new String[]{TAG_EMAIL,
            }, new int[]{
                    R.id.email,});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }


}
```

The snippet for service handler is follow:

```
public class ServiceHandler1 {
    private  String apikey;
    private double lati;
    private  double longi;
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;


    public ServiceHandler1(String key, double latitude, double longitude) {
        apikey=key;
        lati=latitude;
        longi=longitude;

    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type


                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization" , apikey);
                // adding post params
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                //   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", "raiganj, west bengal"));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", String.valueOf(lati)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", String.valueOf(longi)));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

I get images as a link from API. So please help me out.

Comment: i think you have to use volley,Glide,Picaso many third party lib are available to load images as lazzy loading

Comment: You can bind service with activity check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341667/bind-unbind-service-example-android

Comment: @mcd   can i do the same  with service handler.  because i wouldn't  wants to add any  3rd party library

Comment: yes you can but you have to manually handle lazzy loading . :-)  below example using threadpool executor http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134