# Android app in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors

I have to create application and want to use it always when phone works, currently my code is:

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.plan.pedometer">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true"
                 android:name=".PedometerService"/>
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.StartPedometerServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:label="StartPedometerServiceAtBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

StartPedometerServiceAtBootReceiver:

```
public class StartPedometerServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, PedometerService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class PedometerService extends IntentService {

    private int Steps=0;

    public PedometerService() {
        super("Pedometer_Worker_Thread");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        putInSharedPreferences();
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait(1000000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void putInSharedPreferences(){
        stepsNumbers = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("stepsData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editorStepsNumbers=stepsNumbers.edit();
        editorStepsNumbers.putInt(String.valueOf(STEPS),Steps).apply();
    }

}
```

It works if I start `Service` in `MainActivity` by:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),PedometerService.class);
                startService(intent);
```

and Service is running in background but when I restart my phone nothing happens and Service does not start. 
I have one more question, this is `Pedometer` application, where should I put onSensorChange method in Service? Create something like while(1) in onHandleIntent() and put it there?

**UPDATE - my actually code is:**

I followed this tutorial https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services
and tried to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`
AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.plan.pedomoter">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.plan.pedomoter.MyTestService"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.plan.pedomoter.BootBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        launchTestService();
    }
    public void launchTestService() {
        // Construct our Intent specifying the Service
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyTestService.class);
        // Add extras to the bundle
        i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        // Start the service
        startService(i);
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Launch the specified service when this message is received
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class MyTestService extends IntentService {
    Handler handler;
    // Must create a default constructor
    public MyTestService() {
        // Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
        super("test-service");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); // if you override onCreate(), make sure to call super().
        // If a Context object is needed, call getApplicationContext() here.
        handler = new Handler();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MyTestService.this, "start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int i = 0;
            }
        });
        int i=0;
        while(true){
            i++;
            // Do some work here
            if(i>1000)
                i=0;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(MyTestService.this, "stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I used while(true) in MyTestService for check that app is running in background, in project I will use sensors (this is pedometer application) then I want to put something like `MyAlarmReceiver` from tutorial to send data to the server several times a day.

Comment: same as you question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this 
**Manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.mkonuk.rebootapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name=".MyService"/>

        <receiver android:name=".MyBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
 public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service Destroyed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MyBootReceiver**

```
    public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service  = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

I have tested when application started service will be start , even if your application destroyed service will be started again.Even if reboot android device service will be started.

Second question : 
if you will use sensor with service you need to register sensor listener and unregister sensor listener when service destroyed,oncreate method override sensor object and create sensor and sensor manager.In onstartCommand method register generated sensor listener  sensor manager object ,unregister listener when service destroy 
you can check this link 
[Accelemeter in android](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/sensor/android-accelerometer-example/)

if you want to send message from service to activity,you have to implement onbind() method ,activity need to bind on service check this link
[bind activity on service using sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341667/bind-unbind-service-example-android)

[bind/unbind service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341667/bind-unbind-service-example-android)

Comment: Hmm Check my Manifest File, there is this line

Comment: Ohh sorry i did not realize

Comment: to be honest I still do not know what is wrong with my code, there is BroadcastReceiver

Comment: I added <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" /> to Manifest and change for full path (".com.pedometer.receiver.StartPedometerServiceAtBootReceiver") but nothing happend. Can not find any example project for this problem...

Comment: Sorry i have been far away from computer i will check this problem as soon as possible please post all your code

Comment: I edited my post and put there code, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Good to hear  that.Please check as a answer if its answer

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am a little new and looking for the some help, (It is not an answer) I coulndt add any other commentI was trying to execute a similar app, I followed what mithat show,then  when I turn off my mobili it seems like it starts, but just when I put my cellphone password, it appears  a system toast that says "app Stop", so i could t get it. Even when I sweep the app from 'Recent app"  it says "app Stop"
I would like to run it for ever,
thanks