# Stop service and close app

Tags: android, android-activity, service, destroy

My app use a background music service.
I have a button to quit my app but I can't find anything to close my app and my service.
I bind my service to my activity.

I tried:

```
unbindService(serviceConnection);
myService().stopSelf();
stopService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayer.class));
```

and absolutely nothing works !!! The service continues.

How can I do to destroy my service and how can I do to close my app ??

Tx

EDIT:

I use this in the onCreate method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, serviceClass);
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And in the MediaPlayer class

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MediaPlayer getService() {
            return MediaPlayer.this;
        }
    }
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "service bound");
    init();
    return mBinder;
}
```

And that...
But I dont know if I really need to start the service. Bind the service already starts it

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Now I did this

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The onDestroy method works only if i unbind the service !
This doesnt work at all:

```
        getService().stopSelf();
       this.stopService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayer.class));
```

So, how can I stop the service and how can I close the app ?

Comment: How do you start your Service. stopSelf() work only when called from that service.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop your service".  Several of those will stop the service.  However stopping the service won't stop the music unless your service properly handles its onDestroy by stopping the player.

Comment: question is not clear ...do add some code and explanation..

Comment: I though that stopping the service will stop the player too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do in my app. onDestroy() method from the activity will be called when you close your app.

```
private ServiceConnection musicServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicService.LocalBinder binder = (MusicService.LocalBinder) service;
        musicService = binder.getService();
        musicService.setCallbacks(MainActivity.this);
        musicServiceBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MusicService service disconnected (unbinded)");
        musicServiceBound = false;
    }
};


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    bindService(intent1, musicServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    if(musicServiceBound){
        musicService.stopSelf();
        unbindService(musicServiceConnection);
    }
}
```

You wrote `myService()`, where you are creating another service using `()`.
For closing your app programmatically you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically).

Comment: Is it the Service onDestroy ?

Comment: Is the Activity onDestroy

Comment: Do you start your service somewhere or do you just bind it ?

Comment: With this your service will be binded correctly. You can look to other posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341667/bind-unbind-service-example-android