# Communication Between 2 Android Foreground Services : Intents vs Broadcasts?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

So I have two Services in my app **FooService** and **BarService**. What would be the most efficient way to communicate between these services? More specifically, how is communication via sending intents with actions using **startForegrounService** different from sending broadcasts using local broadcast manager?

**Using onStartCommand**

FooService.class

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final int i = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    String intentAction = null;
    if(intent!=null)
        intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if(intentAction ==null)
        return i;
    switch (intentAction) {
        case "Message A":
         // do something with Message A    

            break;
        case "Message B":
         // do something with Message B
        default:
            return i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

BarService.class

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, FooService.class).setAction("Message A");
```

`startService(myIntent`);

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use a LocalBroadCast Manager. Using Intents to start and stop service you will have to handle `onStartCommand` everytime rather start both the services and use LocalBroadCast Manager to communicate is much efficient.

In your Foo Service,

```
LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    }
```

Send your broadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.FooService");
 broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your BarService,

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //Your Action here

        }
    };


@Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((mMessageReceiver),
                new IntentFilter("com.FooService")
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

Comparing a Bound service and a LocalBroadCast manager bound services are much more efficient because they only bind once and can communicate with each other without needing to start any Intents.

[Here is an example explaining the binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341667/bind-unbind-service-example-android)

Comment: Thanks, I understand that we need to handle intents at onStartCommand(). However, I think this is trivial, and more straight-forward than a LocalBroadcastReceiver.

Do you know if one is more efficient than the other? If so, why?