# background service with view

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

i have a background service that collecte some rss data news 
and i need to show just a small view or small activity defiling rss content (no overlay other app)that defile the news as long as the service is alive but i dont now how to acomplich the last part of showing the view
 ps:it well be great if not needed  android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

```
final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

            params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.START;
            params.x = 220;
            params.y = 220;
            params.width = 220;
            params.height = 220;

// my view code 



        windowManager.addView(View, params);
```

Comment: Please clarify the task. Are you creating an [App Widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/)?

Comment: no its a news rss app i need to show a small activity defiling rss content

Comment: It is possible to show activity that is not full screen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog. But when the user presses home button it will go to background.

Comment: It is also possible to show a dialog, it will not hide when home button is pressed. But while it is shown user will not be able to interact with other apps. Also it requires SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

Comment: ah thanx you , how i can call the activity from service please

Comment: To start Activity from Service, use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service. For communication of an existing Activity with a Service, use `bindService()/unbindService()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341667/bind-unbind-service-example-android.