# How to get data from service to activity

Tags: android

In my app I have an activity and a service...
The service will broadcast messages gathered from data from GPS...
The Activity should receive the broadcast messages and update the UI...

my code

```
public class LocationPollerDemo extends Activity {
    private static final int PERIOD = 10000; // 30 minutes
    private PendingIntent pi = null;
    private AlarmManager mgr = null;
    private double lati;
    private double longi;
    private ServiceReceiver serviceReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);

        i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_INTENT, new Intent(this, ServiceReceiver.class));
        i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_PROVIDER, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), PERIOD, pi);

        DebugLog.logTrace("On Create Demo");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location polling every 30 minutes begun", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        serviceReceiver = new ServiceReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("me");
        this.registerReceiver(serviceReceiver, filter);
    }

    class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            File log = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Location2.txt");
            DebugLog.logTrace(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

            try {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log.getAbsolutePath(), log.exists()));

                out.write(new Date().toString());
                out.write(" : ");

                Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
                Location loc = (Location) b.get(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LOCATION);
                String msg;

                if (loc == null) {
                    loc = (Location) b.get(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LASTKNOWN);

                    if (loc == null) {
                        msg = intent.getStringExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR);
                    } else {
                        msg = "TIMEOUT, lastKnown=" + loc.toString();
                    }
                } else {
                    msg = loc.toString();
                }

                if (msg == null) {
                    msg = "Invalid broadcast received!";
                }

                out.write(msg);
                out.write("\n");
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Exception appending to log file", e);
                DebugLog.logException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this code it is not working properly...
I am using **ServiceReceiver** class in separate file works fine....
please tell me...!!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In my Service class I wrote this

```
private static void sendMessageToActivity(Location l, String msg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("GPSLocationUpdates");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    intent.putExtra("Status", msg);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("Location", l);
    intent.putExtra("Location", b);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and at the Activity side we have to receive this Broadcast message

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("GPSLocationUpdates"));
```

By this way you can send message to an Activity.
here **mMessageReceiver** is the class in that class you will perform what ever you want....

in my code I did this....

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("Status");
        Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("Location");
        lastKnownLoc = (Location) b.getParcelable("Location");
        if (lastKnownLoc != null) {
            tvLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(lastKnownLoc.getLatitude()));
            tvLongitude
                    .setText(String.valueOf(lastKnownLoc.getLongitude()));
            tvAccuracy.setText(String.valueOf(lastKnownLoc.getAccuracy()));
            tvTimestamp.setText((new Date(lastKnownLoc.getTime())
                    .toString()));
            tvProvider.setText(lastKnownLoc.getProvider());
        }
        tvStatus.setText(message);
        // Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: and never forget to unregister reciever inside onPause

Comment: @FaisalNaseer How to unregister can you give some sample code please

Comment: Simply `unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver );`

Comment: unregister the receiver on "onDestroy" method :)

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent); is this Activity Context or Service Context ?

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan In service context, in service you can use 'this' keyword for context

Comment: I am torn at this point because this is the only way i know how to send data from service to MainActivity is through broadcasts and they have to be  unregistered during onPause and i want to send data when the app is in the background. For example a music player sending data when music changes eg after media completion. Any recommendations?

Comment: I did the same as above code & getting null exception.                                         
attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.broadcastreceiver.onreceive(android.content.context, android.content.intent)' on a null object reference

Comment: May be you are sending null intent through local broadcast.

Comment: Variable names should be meaningful and readable. "l" and "b" are precisely neither of those.

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager is now deprecated any other way?

Answer (score 12):

A good way to have it is using Handler. 
Create a innerClass in your activity that extends Handler and Override the `handleMessage` method.

Then, in your `ServiceReceiver` class, create a handler variable and a constructor like:

```
public ServiceReceiver(Handler handler){
   this.handler = handler;
}
```

So, in your activity, create your custom handler and pass it to your service. So, when you wants to put some data to your activity, you can put `handler.sendMessage()` in your Service (it will call `handleMessage` of your innerClass).

Answer (score 11):

## How to send data to Activity from IntentService ?

> You don't need to bind a service if the service is meant for one way
>   communication. For such cases using IntentService + BroadcastReceiver
>   is quite easy.
>
> ### Example:
>
> You have a BackgroundService which
>   calculates signal strength and sends back the data to Activity every
>   second. And the Activity shows data in a GraphView.

### How to do that?

[image]

**Send data from Service**

```
public class TrackWifiService extends IntentService {

    public TrackWifiService() {
        super("wifiService");
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        sendDataToActivity()
    }

   private void sendDataToActivity()
   {
        Intent sendLevel = new Intent();
        sendLevel.setAction("GET_SIGNAL_STRENGTH");
        sendLevel.putExtra( "LEVEL_DATA","Strength_Value");
        sendBroadcast(sendLevel);

   }


}
```

**Receive data from Service**
For this, your `Activity` should register with a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class TrackWifiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   WifiLevelReceiver receiver;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.track_wifi_activity_layout);
      receiver = new WifiLevelReceiver();
      registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("GET_SIGNAL_STRENGTH"));  //<----Register
   }


   @Override
   public void onStop()
   {
       super.onStop();
       unregisterReceiver(receiver);           //<-- Unregister to avoid memoryleak
   }

   class WifiLevelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           if(intent.getAction().equals("GET_SIGNAL_STRENGTH"))
           {
              int level = intent.getIntExtra("LEVEL_DATA",0);

              // Show it in GraphView
           }
       }

   }

}
```

### Note:

If you want to use `LocalBroadcastReceiver` instead of a BroadcastReceiver. You can just see check out [How to convert BroadCastReceiver to LocalBroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager/49063575#49063575)

### Relevant Links

[See Full project](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Bulucu)
[What is an IntentService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice/47110145#47110145)
[Difference between Bound and Unbound Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240299/can-anybody-explain-what-is-difference-between-unbound-and-bound-service-in-andr/47093659#47093659)

Comment: If the user minimizes the app, it will unregister the receiver. So better to register it in `onStart()`.

Comment: depends on the use case if you want data even if your app is in the background then register and unregister in bindService() in onCreate() and unbindService() in onDestroy() Read more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614335/android-how-to-safely-unbind-a-service/55593262#55593262   Read more here in the official docs https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Additional_Notes

Answer (score 1):

There are three obvious ways to communicate with `services`

> 1. Using Intents.
> 2. Using AIDL.
> 3. Using the service object itself (as singleton).

Comment: need to add more info about each approach

Comment: the question is clear: how to start communication from service to activity.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val sb = object :SerToBroad(){
        override fun broadcastResult(connected: String?) {
           t(connected)
        }

    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
  fun t(connected: String?)
  {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity@this, connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        startService(Intent(MainActivity@ this, MService::class.java))
        val inf = IntentFilter()
        inf.addAction(MService.ACTION)
        registerReceiver(sb, inf)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        unregisterReceiver(sb)
    }
}
-------------------------------------
//Service class 

    class MService : Service() {
   companion object {const val   ACTION = "MY_ACTION"}
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = ACTION

        intent.putExtra("DATA", "10")

        sendBroadcast(intent)
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }
--------------------------------------------------
broadcast

abstract class SerToBroad : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        val rec = p1?.getStringExtra("DATA")
        broadcastResult(rec)


    }

    abstract fun broadcastResult(connected: String?)
}
```

Comment: This code is illegible.

Comment: I could understand this, but there's a lack of explanation for others