# Can anybody explain what is difference between unbound and bound service in android

Tags: android, android-service

Can anybody explain what is difference between unbound and bound service in android and explain about intent service

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**[Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)**

> A service is bound when an application component binds to it by
>   calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server
>   interface that allows components to interact with the service, send
>   requests, get results, and even do so across processes with
>   interprocess communication (IPC).
>
> When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the
>   service **EXCEPT** If the service was started by
>   [startService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent))

**Unbound Service or Started**

> A service is started when an application component, such as an
>   activity, starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service
>   can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that
>   started it is destroyed.

**BUT**

Most confusion about the Service class actually revolves around what it is not:

> A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself does
>   not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise
>   specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part
>   of.
>
> A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of
>   the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

That is where **IntentService** are used.

**[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService)** is a subclass of Service that uses a worker thread to

> handle all start asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on
>   demand, one at a time.  Clients send requests through
>   startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles
>   each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it
>   runs out of work.

[image: Example]

hope it helps :)

Comment: Clear definitions of each type thank you! I'm just looking into services and trying to find a answer to a question related to this. An Intent Service does not handle requests in parallel, it uses one background thread and queues requests.  Could a Bound service, with its own thread pool be a better approach for scalability?

Comment: You should use a service instead and yes with its own thread pool would be a better approach and choose newFixedThreadPool with a fixed number of cpu(depending on available cpu). I have this approach using mqtt actually and its working gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and advice for using a service - just reading up about mqtt and push notifications .. As soon as I learn about one thing, it invariably leads to a lot of other topics!

Answer (score 11):

Bounded services are bounded to an activity which binds it and will work only till bounded activity is alive.
 while a unbounded service will work till the completion even after activity is destroyed.
a tabular difference is given in below link which is very useful for interviews
http://infobloggall.com/2014/04/15/bounded-service-in-android/

Answer (score 9):

## Bound and Unbound Services are not two sides of a coin

A service can be a bound or unbound(started) or both, It is just the matter of implementation you provide to the callback methods of Service class. See all four callback methods [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics)

But for the **sake of differentiation** here you go

### 1. Staring a service

Unbound Service is started by calling `startService()` method.
Bound Service is started by calling `bindService()` method.
However in both calls system calls [onStartCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) method internally

### 2. Life Span of a service

Once an unboundService is started it runs indefinitely until

- Application component calls [stopService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) method
- Service itself calls [SelfStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf()) method.

BoundService runs as long as the service is bound to a client. When there is no active client bound with the service, the system destroys the Service

### 3. onBind() method

When you are writing a service you will have to override the onBind(). If
Unbound Service then return null
BoundService then return IBinder object.

> Though unbound services does not return Ibinder object it does not mean that it can not interact with application component.
> There are ways to do that for example [BroadCastReceiver](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1mc3emKLXAhUL94MKHbA0DqcQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fcontent%2FBroadcastReceiver.html&usg=AOvVaw21d2Pcj2Zrkafa-Owmphld) or [ResultReceiver](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj17orwmKLXAhXj7IMKHa-JB10QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fos%2FResultReceiver.html&usg=AOvVaw2TxfsrggGyWu3Ohk-aHOvX)

### One way vs Two-way communication with Service

When you want two-way communication with your Service then you should bind your service with Activity.
Eg. Playing music in the background with pause, play option (Activtiy <-> Service).

Go with unbound or started service when you just want your Service to update your Activity (Service->Activity).
Eg: Timer Service which updates Activity every second.

> Another example

You have written some Service which deals with Location changes.
If you want to update your activity when you move 10 meters (Go with unbound service).
If you want to see the coordinates of your current location when you click some button in the activity. (Go with the bound service).

Answer (score 8):

1. Unbound service is started when component (like activity) calls startService() method 
   Where As A service is bound when another component (e.g. client) calls bindService() method.
2. The Unbound service can stop itself by calling the stopSelf() method. 
   Where As The Bound service cannot be stopped until all clients unbind the service.
3. The Unbound service runs in the background indefinitely.
   Where As The Bound service does not run in the background indefinitely.
4. The Unbound service is stopped by stopService() method.
   Where As In The Bound service, The client can unbind the service by calling the unbindService() method.

Thanks

Comment: +1 from me for actually providing a good answer to an old question. Now add a link to the docs at the bottom and I'd consider this a very good answer.