# How to Know When Service/App is Swiped Away

Tags: android, service, swipe, android-lifecycle, kill

I have an app that binds a service which saves data to the phone's file manager at various times during the application's life cycle (the app is in the background while it's doing this). If something happens to invalidate the data, the data should be discarded once the service completes. (Note that it does do so successfully as long as the service's life cycle is uninterrupted). However, if I swipe away the app while the service is running, the data is not discarded.

The issue is that the activity's `onDestroy()` method is never called, while `onStop()` has already occurred because the app is in the background.

Furthermore, the service's `onTaskRemoved()` is never called (possibly because it's a bound service? Yes, I put `android:stopWithTask="false"` in the service's declaration in the manifest), nor is `onUnbind()` or `onTrimMemory()` when the app is swiped away. The service and app just kind of end.

How can I know that the service/app is being killed in order to discard data before that happens?

Comment: remove `android:stopWithTask="false"` from your manifest,  call `startService` and see if `Service#onTaskRemoved` was called

Comment: Can you explain `Service#onTaskRemove`? I have tried without having `android:stopWithTask` in the manifest, and I've overridden `onTaskRemoved` as well as `onUnbind` and `onTrimMemory` and put log statements at the top of them, and none of them get printed when the app is swiped away.

Comment: `Service#onTaskRemoved` is called

Comment: Clearly though, it's not, at least in this case

Comment: what API version did you try in on? i run on 4.4 and `onTaskRemoved` **IS** called

Comment: I'm running on 6.0.1. I think it may have to do with the fact that this is a bound service? I've heard that for bound services, onTaskRemoved is not called.

Comment: So should i run my code on 6.0?

Comment: You could try if you're willing. What kind of service are you using? E.g. is it bound, or is it unbound (called with `StartService()`)

Comment: why "or"? it is both started and bound (i mentioned to call `startService` in my first comment)

Comment: The service documentation ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)) distinguishes between Started services (unbound) and Bound services as two different things. This stackoverflow post's answer defines it the same way ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240299/can-anybody-explain-what-is-difference-between-unbound-and-bound-service-in-andr))

Comment: then make it both bound and started

Comment: But they are two different things... I'm not sure why yours works, but everything I'm looking at says they can't be both bound and started. Can you point me to some documentation that says they can?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html ^F `Binding to a Started Service` is says: `As discussed in the Services document, you can create a service that is both started and bound.` also read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html `Although this documentation generally discusses these two types of services separately, your service can work both ways—it can be started (to run indefinitely) and also allow binding`

Comment: do you see how it works now?

Comment: I think so. Thank you!