# What is the advantage of binding to a Service to get its variables, as opposed to using SharedPrefs, or getting the variables directly?

Tags: android, variables, service

I've got a service meant to sometimes run in the background - started with startService().
What is the advantage of **binding** to this service so as to get/set its variables, instead of - controversial, I know, but still - just accessing its public variables directly (e.g. myVar = mainService.itsVar), or using SharedPrefs to set and get the values? 
Especially, what is the fastest, in terms of performance, based on the fact that the get interval would be roughly 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantage - You can access variables and run methods directly.
Disadvantage - allot of cross thread headache, not to mention unresolved crashes on google developer console.

How to do it correctly, I will give example of a foreground service, if it can be background then change only how to start it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    mContext.startForegroundService(startIntent)
 } else {
    mContext.startService(startIntent);
 }
```

In the service you need to implement all binding methods:

```
private IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

public MainService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return true;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public MainService getService() {
        return com.xxx.xxx.MainService.this;
    }
}
```

In the activity you need to listen to connection:

```
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBoundService = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connecting");
        MainService.MyBinder myBinder = (MainService.MyBinder) service;
        mBoundService = myBinder.getService();
        mShouldUnbind.set(true);
    }
};
```

If other activity or alarm can start your service you will need to check every second or so if the service was started by other and bind to it.
Important - service run on the same thread like the main/GUI thread - so if you have time consumption actions like camera or uploading - you will need to start a background thread. back communication can be made by calling the GUI/main thread.
on foreground service like mine - you need also to manage notifications otherwise the o.s. will kill the service after 5 seconds.

Code example:

```
if (mShouldUnbind.get() && mBoundService != null)
            val = mBoundService.getTimestamp();
```

Edit I:
advantage:
I have a camera foreground service - I can set zoom values directly from the GUI thread since I have a handle to the service. the camera is running on the background thread in the service, but, since the preview is being drawn 30 times pro seconds - the zoom is set without any lag. you will never manage to do it in any other way.

Comment: thanks Kfir, and hello again! +1 but I am letting the question unanswered as I am after a deeper explanation of advantages vs. drawbacks from a variables perspective between the 3 options (e.g. what's the point of accessing the variables "directly"?).

Comment: hello again, since you helped me so much - wanted to give share back some knowledge. and I saw you have this old question waiting for answers. no stress about approving the answer. just wanted to share back from my experience. I will anyhow add some more info to the answer

Comment: I find it's a great example of the relevance of binding to a service to SET its variables; more generally, I realise it has to do with threading optimisation, by the looks of it. 
I was originally interested in the differences involved for the purpose of GETTING variables - I'll look into it a bit more and see whether threading optimisation done in this way could apply to my own use cases. At the time I did bind to the service, and got the variables the right way, but always felt it was a bit over the top. apparently not.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between bounded service and Unbound service, bounded services are bounded to an activity which binds it and will work only till bounded activity is alive. while a unbounded service will work till the completion even after activity is destroyed, see the below link

[Can anybody explain what is difference between unbound and bound service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240299/can-anybody-explain-what-is-difference-between-unbound-and-bound-service-in-andr/29002799)

Comment: thanks Fahad. I have edited my question, to mention that I have an unbound service to begin with (started with startService()). I would like to know the fastest way to get the variables of that service, from an activity: binding to it, or via SharedPrefs, or accessing public variables directly. Basically, what is the use of binding to an unbound service?