# Unable to use TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm writing a GCM application.
I'm unable to set a received message to a text view.

Check the below code:

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

    String mes;
    private Handler handler;

    public GcmMessageHandler() {
        super("GcmMessageHandler");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        mes = extras.getString("title");
        showMsg();
        Log.i("GCM", "Received : (" +messageType+") "+extras.getString("title"));
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    public void showMsg(){
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.getMsg);
                textview.setText(mes );
            }
         });
    }
}
```

(Error msg : The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){})

Comment: I don't think adding text to a textview needs to be in a runnable at all. It's not the error but thought I'd comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to get the reference of your TextView `R.id.getMsg` in the layout. You're using the `findViewById`method in an `IntentService` Class which does not provide this method. [See Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Normally you do that in an `Activity` or `Fragment` in lifecycle methods like onCreate or onCreateView etc. where the View is given as parameter value. That looks similar to the following line of code:

```
TextView textview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.getMsg);
```

After you've retrieved your TextView reference, you're able to use it in implemented methods.

You need a way to handle data from your Intent Service back to your Application/Activity etc. A possible solution could be to pass your retrieved message data from the IntentService back to the Activity you could use a BroadcastReceiver (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125241/how-to-get-data-from-service-to-activity))

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried the below code, now I'm getting error at "view": [view cannot be resolved]                                                                                                           public void showMsg(){
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             
             TextView textview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.getMsg);
    textview.setText(mes );
            }

Answer (score 0):

Your textview is in service class and textview must be at activity
 class . If you want to set data in activity than create an interface
 or make textview public static.