# How to pass data from a service to activity using @Receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-annotations

I am using Android annotation library, and I want to pass data from service to activity using broadcast receiver. I want to utilize `@Reciever` of Android annotation, my attempt is same as this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18761609/5896744)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity`, add this receiver method:

```
@Receiver(actions = "GPSLocationUpdates", local = true)
void receiveLocationUpdates() {
 // TODO
}
```

And broadcast your `Intent` as usual from the `Service`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("GPSLocationUpdates");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```