# Add to a list in an activity from a service

Tags: android, service

I have a `list` declared in my `mainactivity`, also calling the `service` from there but I have encountered some problems with trying to `add` items to the `list` I have from my `service`.

A little background, my `service` is doing some fetching of data and I save the response to a `list` I have in my `main activity`.

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
Activity activity = new Activity();
activity.addError(error);
```

My main activity is like this:

```
List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();    
public void addError(String error) {
    errorList.add(error);
}
```

I'm really quite not sure with all of this. I hope you can help. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125241/how-to-get-data-from-service-to-activity

Comment: Use event bus instead it'll make communication much easier...[link](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#add-eventbus-to-your-project)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by referring to this helpful [post](http://android-coding.blogspot.sg/2011/11/pass-data-from-service-to-activity.html). Hopefully this can help you too.