# How to pass data service to activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, intentservice

I have Three class

> 1.MenuActivity
>
> 2.LocationUpdateService
>
> 3.MultipleMarker

**1.MenuActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        bindService(new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class), mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

**2.LocationUpdateService:**(This is Service Class)

```
   private  void sendMessageToActivity(Location l, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("GPSLocationUpdates");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("Status", msg);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("Location", l);
        intent.putExtra("Location", b);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Sending Data to BroadCast Receiver",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**3.MultipleMarker**(Activity)

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("GPSLocationUpdates"));



 private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("Status");
            Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("Location");

            Log.d("messagesshow","****** "+message);

           Location   lastKnownLoc = (Location) b.getParcelable("Location");
            if (lastKnownLoc != null) {

                Log.d("messagesshow","*****    "+String.valueOf(lastKnownLoc.getLatitude()));

            }

             Toast.makeText(context, "Data Receiver called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

My Problem is that :  When i open My MenuActivity My Toast Messages printing **Sending Data to BroadCast Receiver**  then onclick of Button I am calling MultipleMarker.class there i am not able to getting the values from service...But when i press back button i redirect to MenuActivity at that time i getting values...

I want to get data from my LocationUpdateservice class into in my MultipleMarker.class activity...

Comment: Can you explain  me reason for downvote.

Comment: Hi you can create interface and set that as a listener on activity class and send callbacks from service class.

Comment: @PankajKantPatel Thank you sir..can you give some reference link please..how to set and get

Comment: Please look into bind service code and then use binder object to get instance of service object.i don't have code examples yet

Comment: where do you put LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("GPSLocationUpdates")); ?

Comment: @YinKiet in my service class..Once i get location i calling that function..sir

Comment: @GowthamanM you should put this inside MultipleMarker.class

Comment: @YinKiet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125241/how-to-get-data-from-service-to-activity i refer here sir

Comment: @GowthamanM Do you mind to share your full src for LocationUpdateService and MultipleMarker?

Comment: @YinKiet Thank sir....just i solved my pbm in different way sir...

Comment: @GowthamanM good to hear that

Comment: @YinKiet i have already bind service...from that service i got location updates..then using Bundle i am passing sir.....

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Interface and get your Service's reference following these steps:

In your LocationUpdateService add those attributes:

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service{

    // The Binder is an intern class
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        //The Binder as a method which return the service
        public LocationUpdateService getService() {
            return LocationUpdateService.this;
        }
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

}
```

Then in your MenuActivity:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LocationUpdateService mService;

    // Connection interface to the service
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        // Called when the activity connects to the service
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

        // Here you get the Service
            mService = ((LocationUpdateService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

        }

        // Called when service is disconnected
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mService = null;
        }
    };
}
```

Then your `bindService()` method will call the [`onServiceConnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceConnected(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.IBinder)) and you will get the instance of your *Service*.

**Note**: [`onServiceConnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceConnected(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.IBinder)) is called asynchronously, so you can't use Service's methods right after calling `bindService()` because you'll have a NullPointerException.

Comment: D thank you for your suggestion sir..i will try it..i already start bind service

Comment: In the Activity's onDestroy() method, don't forget to call `unbindService(mConnection)`