# Android : How to detect if my Application class was opened by user click or by itself in background

Tags: android, android-application-class

I wanted to know when my Application class' onCreate is called, whether it was created due to user opening the app or by itself due to some reason like broadcast received/job started etc. Please help.

Comment: Can you please know, how you want to know by notification or By Toas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set boolean variable inside pref. Set this variable to true inside your broadcast/service. 
And Inside `onCreate` method just check for that value. And also set it to false after using it in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be to set a `flag/tag` from your service as described in below post. And in activity check is the `flag/tag` is available and perform necessary operations.

[How to get data from service to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125241/how-to-get-data-from-service-to-activity)