# Handle Android push notification on current Activity

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had implemented Android push notifications and I can handle it when app is running extending `FirebaseMessagingService` with this method:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   ...
}
```

But what I really need is to get the notification data in my current activity to update some fields to the user see it in real time. But I can't find a way to do this. Could someone help me?

Comment: You just need to route the data from the service to your activity, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125241/how-to-get-data-from-service-to-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a local broadcast receiver**

When you receive a notification at FirebaseMessagingService, you will send the data to the activity that you need with a LocalBroadcastReceiver. It's easy and safe.

**On your FirebaseMessagingService**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

//Take the data from message received
String myData = remoteMessage.get("MyDataKey");

//Send data through a local broadcast receiver
Intent intent = new Intent("IntentFilterAction");
intent.putExtra("MyDataKey", myData);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**On activity onCreate**

```
//Create BroadcastReceiver
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          super.onReceive(context, intent);

          //Get data from intent
          String mydata = intent.getExtras
      }
};

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("IntentFilterAction");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

**On activity onDestroy**

```
//Unregister BroadcastReceiver
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

check this out from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-onmessagereceived):

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        updateData(remoteMessage.getData());

    }

}



public void updateData(Map<String, String> data){
        // update your data here
        //ex: editText1.setText("text");
    }
```

Comment: That code in the docs is for a Service, not an activity.  The challenge is getting the data payload to the activity from the service.

Comment: @DanielNugent then maybe try 1) save the data in a shared preferences and retrieve them from the activity. or 2) prepare a [pending intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) and get the data from it when starting your activity.   i think this will solve it if i understand the issue correctly