# Android service isn't working as a singleton

Tags: java, android, singleton

I have a service that is being used/bound in multiple activities (I carefully wrote it so that one activity will unbind it before another binds, in onPause/onResume). However, I noticed a member in the Service won't stick....

Activity 1:

```
private void bindService() {
    // Bind to QueueService
    Intent queueIntent = new Intent(this, QueueService.class);
    bindService(queueIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

...

bindService();

...

mService.addItems(downloads);     // the initial test adds 16 of them
```

Activity 2:

```
bindService();                             // a different one than activity 1
int dlSize = mService.getQueue().size();   // always returns 0 (wrong)
```

Service's code:

```
public class QueueService extends Service {
    private ArrayList<DownloadItem> downloadItems = new ArrayList<DownloadItem();

    // omitted binders, constructor, etc

    public ArrayList<DownloadItem> addItems(ArrayList<DownloadItem> itemsToAdd) {
        downloadItems.addAll(itemsToAdd);
        return downloadItems;
    }

    public ArrayList<DownloadItem> getQueue() {
        return downloadItems;
    }
}
```

Upon changing one thing -- making the service's downloadItems variable into a static one -- everything works perfectly. But having to do that worries me; I've never used a singleton in this way before. Is this the correct method of using one of these?

Comment: Do you call startService() anywhere in your activities? This allows the service to stay alive as a singelton. Otherwise it will be destroyed when the activity which bound to it is destroyed.

Comment: @Nospherus I'll add what I did shortly -- tl;dr does "bindService" work just as well as "startService()"?

Comment: No. You have to call both startService() and bindService(). If you only call bindService(), then the service will die as soon as you unbind it. By calling startService(), it will stay alive until you call stopService()(or stopSelf() inside the service).

Comment: @Nospherus thanks; that's exactly what I needed to know! I will, or would, choose you as best answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out Nospherus was correct; all I needed to do was andd a `startService()` call beside my `bindService()` one, and all was well.

Because multiple `startService()` calls don't call the constructor multiple times, they were exactly what I needed. (This is extremely lazy on my part, but it works for now. I am unsure of how to check for a started (and not bound) service.) My code now looks like this:

```
Intent queueIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QueueService.class);
bindService(queueIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(queueIntent);
```

See also [Bind service to activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916253/bind-service-to-activity-in-android)

Comment: woow , i lost my entire morning searching for a solution of my two instance of service and here it is ... just startService .

Comment: I would startService before binding to it, better practice.

Answer (score 0):

## Service is always Singleton by default

Only one instance of service can ever exist at **a given time**. If a Service is running then there is no way you can create another instance of the Service. Period.

> Binding with multiple Activity

You can bind a service to n number of Activities. Each binding works **independently**. When you move from one Activity to another then the changes done by `Activity1` will persist when you move to `Activity2` **only if the service is alive.**

[image]

> Then why the changes don't persist in my case?
> To understand this we should know the lifespan of a service
>
> ### Lifespan of a Service
>
> A service exist between `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`

**Case 1:**
[image]
**Case 2:**
[image]