# Android - how to pass data from service to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I have a scenario in which the background service needs to pass data to activity after some interval. How to achieve it and what are the possible ways?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind service to activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916253/bind-service-to-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches to achieve what you need. The easiest is to use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver). Register receiver from your activity and send broadcasts from service whenever you need. There are a lot of tutorials on Google on how to use `BroadcastReceivers`.