# Service with "startForeground(..) need to show notification only when app is in background

Tags: android, android-service, background-process

I have a little bit issue for implement service. I make a service to run even when app is in background and even when user proper kill app. I search on internet and see by start service "foreground", service not kill even user kill the app. Then I write a code and it work perfect but the only issue is when I start service by click a button in app the notification immediately show even user is in foreground and that notification only go when I stop service.
I want this notification show only when user go to background not in foreground. I share my code, please help me to solve this issue.
Here is the service class:

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service {

private Handler handler;
private Runnable test;

// Constants
private static final int ID_SERVICE = 101;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String channelId = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? createNotificationChannel(notificationManager) : "";
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(false)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();

        startForeground(ID_SERVICE, notification);
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private String createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager){
    String channelId = "my_service_channelid";
    String channelName = "My Foreground Service";
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    // omitted the LED color
    channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    return channelId;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler = new Handler();
    test = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* GET LOCATION UPDATES */
            Log.i("testApp", "Running...");
            /* GET LOCATION UPDATES */
            handler.postDelayed(test, 2000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(test, 0);
   
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(test);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

And from an activity I start service like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LocationUpdateService.class);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        startForegroundService(intent);
                    } else {
                        startService(intent);
                    }
```

For stop service I use this line:

```
stopService(new Intent(this, LocationUpdateService.class));
```

Comment: `startForegroundService()` requires you to call `startForeground()` on the service or the Android framework will put your app in ANR state. PS you can use `bindService()` to bind your activity to the service and when the activity is destroyed, you can call `startForeground()` in the service to display foreground notification.

Comment: @ashu Thank you for this hint. I try this, if i not understand your point properly. Can you share a code at which point in activity and in service i need to change?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25441663/2410641) is a good starting point. Also see docs for [Context#startForegroundService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) to understand why using it won't work.

Comment: I used to show a notification **only** when my app is **not** in foreground using the ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses. That was on support libraries v25 or something with an Async task. Don't know if that's still applicable nowadays. I only use the 25 because my apps are for personal use only!